# Angular OAuth2 Oidc Bearer Token is in one out of two service instances requests?

Tags: angular, oauth, openid-connect

Generally, because of lazy loading there is two instances of each service, that is being called in my application. Now, this Lib from manfred steyer puts a Bearer Token in a service request only in one instance and the other instance has no token. What could I do to fill both requests?